# jQuery Plugin Authoring: Cannot get basic example to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write a few plugins for jQuery, so as a starting point I went for the basic example shown in the documentation ([here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)). This is the code I have, in a js file called jquery.test.js:

```
(function($) {

   $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) {
     var config = {'foo': 'bar'};

     if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

     this.each(function() {
       // element-specific code here
       alert('found P tag');
     });

     return this;

   });

 })(jQuery);
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Plugin Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.test.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('p').myPlugin();
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>  
        <p>asdgasdgasg</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd expect this to pop up an alert for every paragraph tag in the page. However, when I load the page, nothing happens. Firebug gives me two errors:

```
missing ; before statement
http://playground.darthvader.com/jquery.test.js
Line 16

$("p").myPlugin is not a function
http://playground.darthvader.com/ol.html
Line 11
```

I'm puzzled. Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

EDIT: It turned out there was a typo in the jQuery docs (well caught Ghommey), from which I was copying and pasting the code. I contacted the admins at the docs site, and it's now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  return this;

   });
```

seems to be wrong - try only:

```
  return this;
  };
```

Comment: Yes you're right - the jQuery documentation has a typo! Thanks, I was going nuts...